# Adding days to date in-line in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

prescription.prescriptionDate gives me a proper date object

prescription.prescriptionExpirationDate gives me a number (7, 14)

Please keep in mind I am trying to get this done in-line.

I am trying to add the number 7 or 14 into the date object and it should give me a new date object with the 7 or 14 days added into it. I am definitely doing something wrong as I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDate' of undefined
```

Here's my code:

```
<Typography variant="body2" component="p">
    {new Date(prescription.prescriptionDate).setDate(prescription.prescriptionDate.getDate() + prescription.prescriptionExpirationDate).toDateString()}
   </Typography>
```

Here's the code that works, to prove that I do get infact the prescription.prescriptionDate value correctly.

```
<Typography variant="body2" component="p">
        {new Date(prescription.prescriptionDate).toDateString()}
       </Typography
```

Comment: well, your prescriptionDate is obviously undefined? It works in the Date constructor as it does Date.now when nothing is provided

Comment: my prescriptionDate is not undefined, and it does not answer my question as I am trying to do it inline.

Comment: In addition to the comment by @dube 7/14 is not a number, it's a fraction that resolves to 0.5. *setDate* expects an expression that resoles to an integer and returns the new time value of the date as a number, which doesn't have a *toDateString* method. There seems to be an error in nearly every expression in the statement.

Comment: Please check the main question again, I've edited it to clear up any misunderstanding.

Comment: Put a console.log above it, your prove does not prove anything. new Date(undefined) works because it defaults to "now". But undefined.getDate() does not.

Comment: The [`setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) method does not return a date, just milliseconds... So calling `.toDateString` on an integer will fail.

Comment: I've added a condition for the inline function to run only if the prescription.prescriptionDate is not undefined. I've also console.log'd 
{newDate(prescription.prescriptionDate).toDateString()} and it works. I am getting an error that  prescription.prescriptionDate.getDate is not a function however.

Comment: @dube—passing the undefined value (versus not passing any value) as in `new Date(undefined)` returns an invalid Date. So while it doesn't throw an error, it won't return today's date.

Comment: Until you can post code that replicates the issue (i.e. *toString* returns a valid date but *getDate* throws an error) there's not much that can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *prescription.prescriptionDate* is a Date and *prescription.prescriptionExpirationDate* is a number like 7 or 14, then to keep it on one line as a single expression is the very verbose and inefficient:

```
new Date(new Date(prescription.prescriptionDate).setDate(prescription.prescriptionDate.getDate() + prescription.prescriptionExpirationDate)).toDateString()
```

E.g.

```js
let prescription = {
  prescriptionDate: new Date(),  // Today
  prescriptionExpirationDate: 7  // Days to add
};

let date = new Date(new Date(prescription.prescriptionDate).setDate(prescription.prescriptionDate.getDate() + prescription.prescriptionExpirationDate)).toDateString();

console.log(date); // 7 days from today
```

The error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDate' of undefined
```

is saying that *prescription.prescriptionDate* returns the value *undefined*. The rest of the expression will work, the only issue will be calling *getDate* on *undefined*, e.g.

```js
let prescription = {
  prescriptionExpirationDate: 7  // Days to add
};

try {
  let date = new Date(new Date(prescription.prescriptionDate).setDate(prescription.prescriptionDate.getDate() + prescription.prescriptionExpirationDate)).toDateString();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message); 
}
```

Comment: After further testing, I came to a solution that does not require it to be inline. I absolutely agree with you, thank you for your input. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a function called `addDays` and just render the date by calling the function. It just looks cleaner, especially if you're using React.

```js
/* utils/date.js */
const addDays = (date, days) => {
  const copy = new Date(date.getTime());
  copy.setDate(copy.getDate() + days);
  return copy;
};
// export { addDays };
// ===================================================================
// import { addDays } from 'utils/date';
const MyComponent = () => {
  const state = {
    prescription: {
      prescriptionDate: new Date(),
      prescriptionExpirationDate: 7
    }
  };
  const {
    prescription: {
      prescriptionDate: date,
      prescriptionExpirationDate: expirationDate
    }
  } = state;
  return addDays(date, expirationDate).toDateString(); // Render
};
// export default MyComponent;
// ===================================================================
document.write(MyComponent()); // <MyComponent />
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; font-size: 3em; }
```

Comment: Consider `const addDays = (d, days) => new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() + days)`. ;-)